# how to send binary data using sendMessage

Tags: android, binary, bluetooth

I would like to send a string as a binary string in android.
im using  sendMessage(message);  how can i use that and send binary data?
im trying to send it using the bluetooth to do it.
thank you

Comment: Do you want to send it through SMS?

Comment: You should be more explicit about what sendMessage you are calling. Its hard to help you without knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

The text has encoding, for example UTF16 (not sure whether single encoding for SMS in all countries).
E.g. of UTF16 'а' is \u0410. Initial bytes can be encoded to characters and sent as sms. On receiver side text decoced to bytes using same encoding.